# How can i extract all fields from Column using mysql query

Tags: mysql

The Data in the column is stored in this Format. I am storing Data in JSON format in column

```
{"item": {
    "actor":{
        "time":"2011-08-21 21:56:37",
        "ip":"127.0.0.1",
        "id":"2010072123522251",
        "email":"abc@abc.com",
        "session_id":"c05e3e61a19650b4ca12a21c2e34df5f",
        "loggedout":""},
    "action":{
        "name":"publish",
        "text":"a_id=11714" ,
"a_id":"11714"
    }
}}
```

Now i want the Result like this

time                  ip        id                email             session_id

2011-08-21 21:56:37   127.0.0.1 2010072123522251  2010072123522251  2010072123522251

I used the query like this

```
SUBSTRING(msg,LOCATE('a_id',msg)+5,(LOCATE('"',msg)+2) ) AS answer_id
```

But it is not returning me good results. Some results are terminated. Please suggest

Comment: the way you are storing you data is a bad one, consider redesigning your database structure otherwise you will bump into tons of errors and selects will be a pain. Sorry for not posting any answers, but I don't think anyone can make a general answer to your question

Comment: If you like storing objects like this, consider a NoSQL option like Mongo or Cassandra.

Comment: Basically it is a log output which i am dumping it as a JSON file in db. It is a bad design.But i just need a general Suggestion.not the exact answer if it is possible. I can easily do it using python or perl text processing but i was wondering if i can use mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it using Python text processing. as there is no good way via Sql.

Comment: this is an obvious answer, no? So, you are asking something you already have the answer in your mind

Comment: NO it is not.it is an alternate. I never got the answer in mysql

Comment: lol, you store as json because apply json encode to the input, would not be obvious you use json decode to extract the output?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an answer for you but some thoughts occurred to me that I thought I might share.

Firstly, while I wouldn't recommend it, you could probably write a stored procedure in Java using one of the many JSON parsing libraries to parse the log entry. I don't think MySQL supports this but many other DBMS products (Postgres and Oracle for example) do. One of the many disadvantages is that you will always have to do a full table scan and logs can get very big.

Since you have figured out how to parse it with Python, you might consider doing something like this:

1. Parse the JSON into its constituent elements using python
2. Insert those elements into the database (properly normalised of course) along with the orginal JSON stored as a text BLOB for reference

Now you can do sensible queries like "show me log entries in this date range where the actor email was fred@gmail.com" and be able to take advantage of indexes etc. There's not much reason to retain the original JSON but you might just be glad of it some day when the format unexpectedly changes and you find that none of your parsing works.

Phil